# Does the "GRUB rescue" message means corrupted OS?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, grub, bootloader

Recently I've found that one of my hard drive are going to fail so I bought a new one yesterday. The OS hard drive ( It got a dual boot Windows 7 and Linux Mint, it will go to windows boot menu then the grub menu ) is healthy while the data hard drive is bad.

As I mean to unplug the bad hard drive after the backup, I just left the case open while I am doing the copying. I also unscrew my heatsink because it got into my way for the power cord. After I successfully connected my new hard drive to the PC, I didn't put the heatsink on the CPU.

I tried to boot it up without using the heatsink because screwing it is too much trouble, then it just died after some 10 seconds. ( I think it overheated )

So I put the heatsink back without screwing it because later I would need to re-organize the drives.

When I boot it up it said something about "unknown filesystem grub rescue>". I tried to select the OS hard drive on the boot menu manually but it got the same result. Finally I had to use my live linux usb to boot up the pc.

Does anyone got a clue? I had boot into windows just before I opened the case and it is working. Did I just corrupted my OS drive?

Answer (score 0):

Recovery GRUB:

Inspect the current prefix (and other preset variables):

```
set
```

Find out which devices are available:

```
ls
```

Set to the correct value, which might be something like this:

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod normal
normal
```

After load OS:

```
sudo upgrade-from-grub-legacy
```

27.1 GRUB only offers a rescue shell:

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell.html

Ubuntu liveCD recovery sample:

http://zeasite.com/blog/grub-error-fix-rescue-for-windows-xp-vista-7-8-linux/ubuntu/

Good luck!

Comment: Is it easier to reinstall the OS?

Comment: Then Your have to choose. Try 10 minutes few commands if can not work - reinstall OS. GL!